# How to display alert in xcode source editor extension

Tags: swift, macos, xcodekit

I'm building a source editor extension and when it gets triggered I want to show an alert.

I tried this:

```
let alert = NSAlert()
alert.messageText = "Hello world"
alert.informativeText = "Information text"
alert.addButton(withTitle: "OK")
alert.addButton(withTitle: "Cancel")
alert.runModal()
```

But I get this error:

> Exception: NSWindow drag regions should only be invalidated on the
>   Main Thread! NSWindow drag regions should only be invalidated on the
>   Main Thread!

Thank you in advance

Comment: have you tried DispatchQueue ?

Comment: Yes I put it in this code DispatchQueue.main.async {
            
        } but I get the same error

Comment: I managed to get the alert with DispatchQueue.main.async but the Alert will be displayed under the Editor in XCode.